# RegEx: Extracting name between text

Tags: regex, text-extraction

I have following text patterns:

> An issue was addressed. We would like to acknowledge Jon Doe
>   (facebook.com/JD) for reporting this issue.

and

> An was addressed. We would like to acknowledge
>   Martin Luther King of Union Inc for reporting this
>   issue.

In both text I have to extract proper noun for instances `Jon Doe` from text 1 and `Martin Luther King` and `Union Inc` from text2. Below is my attempt but not working to extract text

```
(We would like to acknowledge) (\w)* of
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easy to retrieve the receiver of the acknowledgements:

```
We would like to acknowledge\b\s*(.*?)\b\s*for reporting this issue.$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/89sUxa/1). This will retrieve the name in the first matching group.

For processing the name further, we need better specifications, like how to handle the parentheses, the word `of`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would match anything between "akcnowledge" and "for" and then process text further. The first `group` should be text between that text.

`/acknowledge(.*)for/g`